# Calling const from parameter in golang

Tags: go

so I want to make my project having a project sets like this

```
 GoTraining
   -Controllers
       ListController
   -Service
       ListService that doing business process and
       calling data Access Object (DAO) to get data
   -DAO
       List query and Model(Const)
   -.gitignore
   -config.conf
   -main.go
   -readme.md
```

that just the picture of my structure , and now come where I get confused
I create a package in dao called customerDao.go and write all of my query inside **const** and I try to make a function called queryFilter with queryType as the parameter and I want to search the const base on the queryType I got as parameter for some reason it give me an error message said that

**"Syntax Error : unexpected const, expecting expression(8,16)"**
[image]

can anyone tell me what I do wrong here?

Comment: `const` is a keyword, you should access it normally `queryGetAllCustomer` as any other variable

Comment: Please take a [go lang tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) for checking how variables and constants are declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're assuming that `queryGetAllCustomer` "belongs to" `const`. Const is not a scope but just an access modifier though, these two snippets produce identical results:

```
const (
    queryGetAllCustomer = "..."
    queryGetOneCustomer = "..."
)

// and...

const queryGetAllCustomer = "..."
const queryGetOneCustomer = "..."
```

You can therefore simply reference the value with `queryGetAllCustomer` (or `dao.QueryGetAllCustomer` from another package, had it been exported):

```
queryText := queryGetAllCustomer
```